# navigating through this xml structure with php

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Im trying to loop through and display info from the following xml structure.

```
<users_list>
  −<users type="array">
    +<user>
      <id>Blah</id>
    </user>
    +<user></user>
    +<user></user>
  </users>
  <next_link>6</next_link>
  <prev_link>4</prev_link>
</users_list>
```

Im using the following PHP to grab the nodes.

```
        $xml = simplexml_load_string($rawxml);
        foreach($xml->users_list AS $key){
            $name = $key->users->user->{"id"};
        }
            $next = $key->{"next_link"};
            $prev = $key->{"prev_link"};
```

Ive tried a couple variations, but i dont see any effect. I either get nothing when i echo my variables, or invalid arguments when on my `foreach` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using SimpleXML, you should always name your variables after the root node they contain, it makes things simpler and obvious:

```
$users_list = simplexml_load_string(
    '<users_list>
      <users type="array">
        <user>
          <id>Blah</id>
        </user>
        <user></user>
        <user></user>
      </users>
      <next_link>6</next_link>
      <prev_link>4</prev_link>
    </users_list>'
);

foreach ($users_list->users->user as $user)
{
    echo "User ", $user->id, "\n";
}

echo "next: ", $users_list->next_link, "\n";
echo "prev: ", $users_list->prev_link, "\n";
```

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in functions.php on line 55 Array -- Thats what i get when i use this method.

Comment: The code I've published works as-is. My guess is your variable isn't named $users_list. Try `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Answer (score 2):

When troubleshooting in PHP, `var_dump` and `print_r` are your friend!

If you wish to browse your result like an array, then cast it to an array.

`$value = (array) $value;`

I did the following:

```
$xmlStr = '<users_list>
<users type="array">
<user>
<id>Blah</id>
</user>
<user></user>
<user></user>
</users>
<next_link>6</next_link>
<prev_link>4</prev_link>
</users_list>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlStr); 

foreach($xml->users->user AS $key=>$value){
    $value = (array) $value;
    $name = $value["id"];
    var_dump($name);
}
```

which gives the output:

```
string(4) "Blah"
NULL
NULL
```

Check the PHP help documents for further info on simplexml

- http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php
- http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php

Comment: Note that print_r() and var_dump() just don't work so well with SimpleXMLElement, children won't appear and some attributes won't either.

Answer (score 0):

`print_r($xml)` should give you all the information you need.
You will probably find that the actual array is $xml->user_list->users->user,
also casting helps save some time

```
foreach($xml->user_list->users->user as $value) {
  $name = (string) $value->id;
}
```